# Having problems creating a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, function

I'm creating a plugin that makes the page (or an element) fade out when you click on a link and fade in when you load the page. The code I have is not working on my demo page though, so I ask if you can take a look at it?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Smoode</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            margin:10px auto;
            background:#DDD;
            padding:10px;
            width:500px;
            border:5px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="smoode.html" class="smoode">
            Smoode!
        </a><br />
        <a href="smoode.html">Not smoode</a>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.smoode = function() {
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            linkClass: "*",
            fadeElement: "body",
            fadeDuration: "300"
        }, options );
        $(document).load(function(){
            $(settings.fadeElement).hide();
            $(settings.fadeElement).fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);
        });
        return this.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(settings.fadeElement).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration).setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            }, settings.fadeDuration);
        });
    }; 
})( jQuery );

$(".smoode").smoode({
    fadeElement: ".container",
    fadeDuration: "1000"
});
</script>
</html>
```

I'm guessing the problem is maybe in where I use "return" and how I put in the variables from "settings" but I'm not sure how I should do it.

Comment: you don't pass the options to your smoode function.

Comment: How would I do that? I copy pasted that from the documentation, and otherwise it looks fine?

Comment: See answer below. I believe you copied a version that didn't have options going in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the options to the plugin, remove `$(document).load(function(){ ...` as the document has no onload function, and it never triggers, and use the callback for animated methods, no need for a timeout (and timeouts can't be chained btw) :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.smoode = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            linkClass: "*",
            fadeElement: "body",
            fadeDuration: "300"
        }, options);

        $(settings.fadeElement).hide().fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);

        return this.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            $(settings.fadeElement).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration, function () {
                window.location.href = self.href;
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $(".smoode").smoode({
        fadeElement: ".container",
        fadeDuration: "1000"
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWVS3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) The only problem is that "this.href" comes out as undefined (when I click on the smoode link I get redirected to /undefined instead of /smoode.html on my local demo)

Comment: @Schart - scoping issue, fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.smoode = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            linkClass: "*",
            fadeElement: "body",
            fadeDuration: "300"
        }, options);

        $(document).load(function () {
            $(settings.fadeElement).hide();
            $(settings.fadeElement).fadeIn(settings.fadeDuration);
        });

        return this.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(settings.fadeElement).fadeOut(settings.fadeDuration).setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            }, settings.fadeDuration);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(".smoode").smoode({
    fadeElement: ".container",
    fadeDuration: "1000"
});
```

Comment: This makes the fadeOut work, but still no redirect and the fadeDuration stays 300 no matter what I put in. Any idea how I'll fix this?